# IONIC Full URL API Path

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

#### Problem

I am facing a problem of getting the full `URL` to my API. 
It does not read/listen to the folder path

#### Output

#### `http://202.57.62.129/api/register/` The `/demos/clientX/` is omitted

see pic bellow

[image: a busy cat]

### Code

#### register.service.ts

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register ts Service File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { appConfig } from '../../shared/app.config'

@Injectable()

export class RegisterService {

    constructor ( private http: Http) {  }

    public doLogin(credentials) {
        return this.http.post( 'http://202.57.62.129/demos/clientX/api/register/', credentials, { headers : appConfig.headers } )
        .map( (res) => { res } )
        .catch( (error: Response) => Observable.throw(error) )
    }
}
```

#### Question

How do I get the full url of my API including the folder paths?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could it be possible that your app is encoding the URL before it can be fired ? An encoding might be causing characters to be missed.

Comment: Any recommendations?

Comment: You will have to go through your code to be sure. Possibly regex is being used somewhere.